# Finding keys of an array of hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, key

I have an array of hash with different keys across the array:

```
csv = [{:fruit=>"apple", :number=>23},{:age=>12,:name=>"XYZ"}]
```

How do I get all the keys like this:

```
[:fruit,:number,:age,:name]
```

I tried

```
array = csv.collect {|key,value| key }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
csv.reduce(&:merge).keys
  #=> [:fruit, :number, :age, :name]
```

Just sayin'

Comment: While I always appreciate a greenie, in this case I don't deserve it, because my solution does more work than is required to just get the unique keys. (Hence, "Just sayin".) I suggest you reconsider your selection. Do note, however, that without `.keys` this is a nice way to convert an array of hashes to a hash (at least when duplicate keys are not a problem).

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) with [`keys`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-key):

```
csv.flat_map { |a| a.keys }
# => [:fruit, :number, :age, :name]
```

If there are multiple instances of some keys, and you want to have each key only once, you should also add [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
csv = [{:fruit=>"apple", :number=>23},{:age=>12,:name=>"XYZ", :number=>11}]
array = csv.flat_map { |a| a.keys }
# => [:fruit, :number, :age, :name, :number]
array.uniq
# => [:fruit, :number, :age, :name]
```

Comment: @LukasBaliak, yes, you can use the `&:keys` shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Without braces or pipes:

```
csv.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
```

or:

```
csv.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq
```